# Defining propTypes throws an error in WebPack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my previous React project I was able to define propTypes before my constructor like this

```
static contextTypes = {
    propToBePassed: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

But in my new project WebPack is throwing an Unexpected token error with the carrot pointing to the = character.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What are you using to compile that syntax to ES5? If it's the newer Babel 6, then the transform for `static propName = value` is not included by default; see [the class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: Thanks Michelle, I'll add a bit of clarification as the Babel docs are very minimal. For me this needed to be added to my devDependencies in my package.json. Then referenced in the plugins array within my WebPack config rather than just the .babelrc file like the docs say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're exporting directly your class declaration and using Babel < 6.2, you'll have to separate it on two different lines like:

```
import { Component } from 'react'

class Button extends Component {}
export default Button
```

Depending on your versions, enable the `classProperties` transform in your Babel options.

You could also look at the [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) babel docs which tells you to use the `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` module like Michelle [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794732/defining-proptypes-throws-an-error-in-webpack/34795640#comment57333857_34794732).